# Java: declaring mixed classes from a hierarchy

Tags: java, object

Suppose you have an animal inheritance hierarchy.  Animal class at the top, Mammal, Fish etc below that, and species (Dog, Cat, Salmon etc below that).  Why would someone declare a class such as:

Animal Rover = new Dog();

rather than

Dog Rover = new Dog();

What are the advantages and disadvantages of doing it this way?

Comment: Read about polymorphism

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12159601/why-do-we-assign-a-parent-reference-to-the-child-object-in-java

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32142128/polymorphism-in-java-why-do-we-set-parent-reference-to-child-object

Comment: This has been asked _so many times_ before.  But one of the key ideas is that by using a variable of type `Animal` instead of a variable of type `Dog`, you communicate to anyone maintaining your code in the future that you are not using any Dog-specific logic on that variable.  Using your code to communicate design intentions is a key part of maintainability.